# Regex Parse Text as Arguments

Tags: regex, arguments, command-line-arguments

I am creating a chat bot for Steam, and the users will be able to type a command such as `!tell jimmy message`. I want this to act exactly like as if it was run with the command line with arguments. So text between quotes count as one single argument, and spaces between text are sperate arguments.

Here are some examples:

- `!tell jimmy message =` **name:** jimmy, **msg:** message
- `!tell jimmy "message" =` **name:** jimmy, **msg:** message
- `!tell jimmy "Hello Jimmy!" =` **name:** jimmy, **msg:** Hello Jimmy!
- `!tell "jimmy" hey =` **name:** jimmy, **msg:** hey

Is this possible with regex and capture groups and if so, how?

Comment: "(.*?)"|(\w+) seems to do something similar to what I am looking for, but the capture groups aren't consistant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern `!tell ("[^"]*"|[^ ]+) ("[^"]*"|[^=]+) =` where you first match `!tell` then you either match a string inside between two quotes `"[^"]*"` or until a space `[^ ]+`. The same applies for the message.

Comment: This seems to be working really well! I'll try and use it and see how I go